# Is there a way to delete Firebase-Storage data if the whole data doesn't get uploaded?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm uploading multiple images to Firebase-Storage.

The problem is if i try to upload 5 images. 2/5 images gets uploaded and I kill the app the uninstall it without reopening it then the two images gets uploaded to firebase storage but the other 3 didn't. And the way I'm storing "download url" is like if all the 5 images gets uploaded then store the url with other data to Firestore and if it fails then don't store download url which means that other data won't get uploaded to Firestore.

**This is the function I use to upload multiple images to database.**

```
    private fun uploadImages() {
    // to store mutliple url's
    val imagesUrl = ArrayList<String>() 
    // mUriImagesList is an arraylist of images
    if (mUriImagesList.isNotEmpty()) { 
        for (image in mUriImagesList) {
            // ref = some storage path //
            val uploadTask = ref.putFile(image)

            val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
                if(!task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                    }
                }
                ref.downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        val downloadUri = task.result
                        imagesUrl.add(downloadUri.toString())
                        if(imagesUrl.size == mUriImagesList.size) {
                            // some other data which will uploaded to firestore if all the images get uploaded to storage
                            uploadMomentData(imagesUrl)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(NEW_FRAGMENT_TAG, "Task FAILED")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to delete those 2 images from the storage if all the images failed to upload? - I thought to write a cloud function but what will be the condition? As there is no way to determine the data uploaded to Firebase-storage is not associated in anyway to firestore(by download url).

Comment: I have done this in java :

Comment: It'll work. Feel free to share your solution @bugfreerammohan

Comment: wait I am updating the answer

Comment: try this It is working perfact

Comment: You will have to track for yourself if previously uploaded files need to be deleted for some reason.  Cloud Storage will not do this for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson So should I upload one by one images to storage with parallel to firestore data. Like for example - i may store the no. of images I want to upload and then if the no. of download url didn't matched the no. of images count - I should delete the whole data? Or you have any other idea?

Comment: Do whatever makes sense for your app.  I don't have a strong opinion.